# Add next and prev button in slide show

Tags: javascript

**HTML**

```
<img id="myImg"src="slide/2.jpg" name="img" width="1000" height="250"/>
```

**JS**

```
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "slide/23.jpg";

var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "slide/7.jpg";

var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "slide/4.jpg";

var image4 = new Image();
image4.src = "slide/5.jpg";

var image5 = new Image();
image5.src = "slide/6.jpg";



var step = 1;

function slideImages() {
    if (!document.images) {
        return
        document.images.img.src = eval("image" + step + ".src");
    }
    if (step < 5) {
        step++;
    } else {
        step = 1;
        setTimeout("slideImages()", 3000);
    }
}

slideImages();
```

Comment: What is your problem? Have you tried reinstalling windows?

Comment: Not a question. You haven't described a problem, attempted to solve it, show the solution, or described difficulties in the solution.

Comment: `eval`? `new Image`? Good grief!

Comment: actually i just made this program for slide show it is working well but i want to use previous and next buttons in the slide show and i dont have any idea how to do that so i put this here please help for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line will never execute.

```
setTimeout("slideImages()", 3000);
```

Because you are calling the `slideImages` function only once with `step = 1` and hence it will not go through the else case.

Try this.

```
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "slide/23.jpg";

var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "slide/7.jpg";

var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "slide/4.jpg";

var image4 = new Image();
image4.src = "slide/5.jpg";

var image5 = new Image();
image5.src = "slide/6.jpg";



var step = 1;

function slideImages() {
    console.log('here' + step);
    if (!document.images) {
        return
    }
    document.images.img.src = eval("image" + step + ".src");
    if (step < 5) {
        step++;
    } else {
        step = 1;
    }
    setTimeout(slideImages, 3000);
}

slideImages();
```

Comment: actually i just made this program for slide show it is working well but i want to use previous and next buttons in the slide show and i dont have any idea how to do that so i put this here please help for the same

Comment: If this question is answered, please accept the answer and post a new question for your new issue.